# Exponential map between $\mathfrak{so} (3)$ and $SO (3)$

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, group-homomorphism, matrix-exponential, semisimple-lie-algebras

I've tried to build $SO (3)$ starting from $\mathfrak{su} (2)$ and the Pauli matrices. I easily computed the elements in $\mathfrak{so} (3)$ by applying the homomorphic map
$$
\mathcal{L} \to \mathcal{L'}, \quad 
a \mapsto \Psi (a)_{jk} = \dfrac{1}{2} \operatorname{Tr} \bigl( \sigma_j [a, \sigma_k] \bigr),
$$

where $\sigma_i$ are the Pauli matrices and $\mathfrak{su}(2)$ generators. But when trying to apply an exponential map s.t.
$$
\theta (\Psi) = e^{\Psi (a)} 
= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{k!} \left(\Psi (a) \right)^k \in SO (3),
$$
I couldn't succeed.

Comment: *Notation:* `\operatorname{Tr}` typesets the text in roman (upright) style but also incorporates conventions of whitespace, limits (sub- and superscript), line breaks, etc. of the standard operators such as `\log` and `\lim`.

Comment: Hint, Define $A_{i, j}(a)=\sigma_{j}[a, \sigma_{k}]$, If it's really going to happen, try applying, $e^{\operatorname{Tr}[A_{i, j}(a)]}=\det(e^{A_{i, j}(a)})$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm only a physicist, so I don't know the level of rigor you are after. You constructed 3×3 antisymmetric, hence traceless matrices $\Psi(a)=-\Psi(a)^T$, depending on the 3-vector parameters $\vec a$, implicit in your $a=\vec a\cdot \vec \sigma$.

The exponential of $\Psi(a)$ is then an orthogonal matrix *O*,
$$
O(a) O(a)^T =e^{\Psi(a)}  e^{-\Psi(a)}= {\mathbb I};  
$$
but *O* is also unimodular, as
$$
\det O(a)=e^{\operatorname{Tr}(\log e^{O})}= e^{\operatorname{Tr} O}=1.
$$
Don't you define SO(3) as the group represented by orthogonal unimodular
3×3  matrices?